# Counting the ways to form multiple committees

Tags: combinatorics

Fix $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Let $\mathcal{P}_{k,n}$ denote the set of ordered $n$-tuples $(k_1, \dots, k_{n})$ such that $k_1 + \dots + k_{n} = k$. What is
\begin{align}
\sum_{(k_1, \dots, k_{n}) \in \mathcal{P}_{k,n}} \binom{k}{k_1} \binom{k-k_1}{k_2} \binom{k-k_1-k_2}{k_3} \cdots \binom{k-k_1-\dots-k_{n-2}}{k_{n-1}} \,?
\end{align}

Of course, one can add the $\binom{k-k_1- \cdots- k_{n-1}}{k_{n}}$ term above, but note that this is just equal to $1$ because the top term is equal to $k_{n}$.

Is the sum above equal to the number of ways to create $n$ committees out of $k$ people?

Comment: Why did you write $k_{2^n}$ in your ordered tuple?  Is that a typo?  Are we assuming each $k_i \in \Bbb N$?  If so, then the number you're calling $\mathcal P_{k, n}$ is easily calculated using a technique often called here "stars and bars."  It's $\binom {k+n-1}{n-1}$.

Comment: Do you allow the $k_i$ to equal $0$ or should they all be strictly positive?

Comment: @RobertShore I don't think that is correct. For $n=k=2$, the possible partitions of $k$ are $(k_1,k_2)=(0,2),(1,1),(2,0)$, so we get the value $\binom20+\binom21+\binom22=4$, which does not match $\binom{2+2-1}{2-1}=3$. The result should be $n^k$, for example by the multinomial theorem.

Comment: @RobertShore indeed this was a typo that has now been corrected. The $k_i$ are non-negative integers. As Stefan Albrecht has pointed out, it seems that stars and bars is not the correct approach. Note that stars and bars counts the number of partitions of $k$ into $n$ pieces, but in the sum I wish to compute, each partition carries a weight.

Comment: @StefanAlbrecht Thank you so much for pointing me to the multinomial theorem. I didn't realize that the terms in my sum are equivalent to multinomial coefficients. Would you mind turning your comment into a complete answer? Otherwise, I can write something.